# How to prove this ratio is less than $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

I've been trying to figure out how to prove that for the sequence $x_n=\sqrt{n}$, $$\frac{\left|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1} \right|}{\left| x_{n+1}-x_n \right|}=\frac{\left|\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1} \right|}{\left| \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \right|}<1.$$

It seems that I've tried several approaches, but the best I could arrive at was this: $$\left|\left|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1} \right|-{\left| x_{n+1}-x_n \right|}\right|<\left|\left|x_{n+1}-x_{n} \right|-{\left| x_{n}-x_{n-1} \right|}\right|.$$ Not sure how this may help though.

Would appreciate some hints...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Here's what I did: $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$, $\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}$. Thus $\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{2\sqrt{n+1}}{2\sqrt{n+1}}=1$. Seems to look correct.

Comment: @sequence Look good to me.

Answer (score 2):

One way of solving this problem is: *Approximate the discrete with continuum!*

Consider the function $f(x)=\sqrt x$, for $x\ge1$. The derivative $f'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt x}$ is positive and so $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x>1$. But $f'(x)$ itself is a decreasing function for $ x>1$. So the function f$ $despites being increasing, increases less and less for higher $x$.

So the differences will be less. That is $\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}$ will be less than $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n$.

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as P Vanchinathan's answer , consider the function $$f(n)=\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\right) \left(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}\right)$$ Its derivative write, after simplifcation, $$f'(n)=\frac{\left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\right) \left(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}\right)
   \left(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}\right)}{2 \sqrt{n(n+1)(n+2)}}$$ which is positive.

Now, you could use Taylor expansions for large values of $n$ (factoring $n$ for each radical and using the generalized binomial theorem) to get $$f(n)=1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{5}{8 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: "In the same spirit", perhaps, but hugely more complicated, no?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\totald{}{x}\pars{\root{x + 1} - \root{x}} = -\,{1 \over 2}
\pars{{1 \over \root{x}} - {1 \over \root{x + 1}}} < 0
\end{align}

> $\ds{\implies \root{x + 1} - \root{x}}$ is a *decreasing function* of $\ds{x}$

$$
\implies \root{n + 2} - \root{n + 1} < \root{n + 1} - \root{n}
$$